# netcoreapp3.0 console application publish fails with PublishTrimmed true

Tags: c#, .net-core, netcoreapp3.0

Everything works fine without `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>`.
The error message below doesn't offer any insights :(

**error:**

```
11.11.2019 13:33:57
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<IsBuildCompletedSuccessfully>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<DefaultCorePublishStep>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__202.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---

System.Exception: Publishing failed.

===================
```

**project.csproj:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  // ...

</Project>
```

**dotnet --list-sdks:**

```
D:\> dotnet --list-sdks
1.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
1.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
1.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-rc1-014190 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

D:\>
```

Comment: As a starting point try setting `<PublishReadyToRunShowWarnings>true</PublishReadyToRunShowWarnings>` to see if there are any warning shown which might indicate a problem with your code, otherwise this might be a bug in the SDK.

Comment: No, no reflection. At least not anywhere in my code. Of course I cannot claim that for any nuget package I reference.

Comment: The trimmed feature is still in development, so you might consider reporting it as a bug to Microsoft and share your sample with them.